# Degrees of compactifications of affine space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field and $V\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ a smooth variety over $k$.  (Note: not assuming $k$ is algebraically closed).  Now assume that for some point (I'm willing to assume every point), the variety $V\setminus T_pV$ is isomorphic to an affine space.  What can be said about the degree of $V$?

I know that for $d=2$, this is true.  Can it happen for anything that isn't a quadric, or does this property determine that you have a quadric, automatically?

Comment: If you take the twisted cubic in P^3 and throw away one tangent line, you get A^1.  You can just repeat this for any Veronese image of P^1.

Comment: $V$ must necessarily be rational and I think there are many examples. For example, take any smooth rational curve with the property that the tangent lines and secant lines are disjoint (except at points of the curve itself of course). This happens in particular for all rational normal curves. Then $V-T_p=V-p$ is isomorphic to $A^1$. If I'm not mistaken, the above property can be ensured by a embedding the curve using a sufficiently ample line bundle.

Comment: ..so in particular, the degree can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Maybe for hypersurfaces it could still be true?

Comment: @quim I was just about to ask if it is true for hypersurfaces, or if it becomes true if I say instead of $V\setminus T_pV$, $V\setminus H$ where $H$ is a hyperplane containing $T_pV$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give some remarks assuming that $k=\mathbb C$.

**a.** The intersection $T_p V \cap V$ must have codimension one. Otherwise $H^0(\mathbb C^n,\mathcal O_{\mathbb C^n})$ would inject into $H^0 (V,\mathcal O_V)$.

**b.** If $T_p V \cap V$ is reduced and irreducible then $V$ is a Fano manifold with $Pic(V)=\mathbb Z$ and therefore has bounded degree.

**c.** If you are not in the cases of dimension one or codimension one, and you assume that your property holds for every $p\in V$  then the second fundamental form of $V$ is everywhere degenerated. Griffiths-Harris' [Algebraic geometry and local differential geometry](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=ASENS_1979_4_12_3_355_0) maybe useful in this case.

---

The following remarks are not about the original question, but rather to one of Charles' comments:
"or if it becomes true if I say instead of $V∖T_p V, V∖H$ where $H$ is a hyperplane containing $T_pV$.

**d.** As already noted by  mdeland in the comments 
the rational normal curves give examples of curves $C$ such that
$C \setminus T_p C \simeq \mathbb A^1$. Moreover, if we consider 
the osculating hyperplane $H_p$ of $C$ at $p$ then $C \setminus H_p$
is also isomorphic to $\mathbb A^1$.

**e.** There are $3$-dimensional examples coming from the study of compactifications of $\mathbb C^3$.

Let  $V_5 \subset \mathbb P^6$ be the Fano $3$-fold of index two and degree $5$. 
 This  $3$-fold can be described as the intersection of $Gr(2,5) \hookrightarrow \mathbb P^9$ with $3$ generic hyperplanes (they are all isomorphic). Alternatively, it can be 
described as closure of the $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb P^1)$-orbit of the vertices of a
regular octahedron in $\mathrm{Sym}^6\mathbb P^1$.

I think it was Furushima who first presented an explicit hyperplane $H\subset \mathbb P^6$
such that $V_5 \setminus H \simeq \mathbb C^3$.

Later a number of other divisors in $V_5$ with complement isomorphic to $\mathbb C^3$ where
found.  There are also divisors in Fano $3$-folds of index one with complement isomorphic to $\mathbb C^3$.

Anyway,I think  you  find useful information in the literature about compactifications
of $\mathbb C^3$. I would start  looking  at Mukai's  Fano $3$-folds, and  Peternell-Schneider's Compactifications of $\mathbb C^n$: a survey.